# Values obtained in the output are not sorted in a proper order

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner in PHP and I have tried hard to make a ToDo list using PHP and MySQL which gives an output of the tasks as shown in below image:

[Final Output of my ToDo list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IvJ3.png)

Everything is working fine. I can add tasks through a form, retrieve them in a table, and even delete them using a delete button beside every row as shown in the above image. Everything was fine until I noticed that the list of tasks weren't ordered by ID. As you can see in the above image, ID 40 is in the top and ID 39 is in the lower part. Frankly speaking, arrangement of every ID is messed up after I get the output as shown in the image.

I want to obtain an output that would order my Tasks in ascending order of my IDs.

How can I do it?

For your kind consideration I am embedding the code of my file that throws out the output below.

**view.php**

```
  <?php
  ob_start();
  include('connect.php');
  $selectFrom = "SELECT * FROM todo";
  $q = $connection->query($selectFrom);
  $totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($q);
  for ( $i=1; $i<=$totalRows; $i++) {
  $arrayResult = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
  include('table.php');
  }
  if (isset($_GET['del_task'])) {
  $id = $_GET['del_task'];

  mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM todo WHERE id=".$id);
    header('location: view.php');
  }

  $tasks = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tasks");
  mysqli_close($connection);
  ?>
```

Comment: use `order by ID`

Comment: You could just add ORDER BY id to the end of your to-do select query at the top.

Comment: Yes just order in your MySQL query, not PHP.

Comment: Good choice on using mysqli, but try to stay consistent with your syntax. You can use object-oriented ($connection->query) or procedural (mysqli_query($connection,..)) syntax but  you're using both in this code. Just stick to one for cleaner code.

Comment: It seems like I have not learned much about basic MySQL. Thank you sir, the fix that you all provided really helped. Thanks Jens, Jhilgeman, xander.

Comment: Actually, I am learning by myself through the internet by using various available video resources and books (Your Suggestions needed for good quality learning resources). To say, I am just starting to code. I will try to be consistent on mysqli as I find it quite easy to remember. Thank you sir  @jhilgeman for your good advice.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Be **extremely** careful when using "available video resources". 99% of YouTube tutorials about PHP and MySQL are awful. Resources like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help you find better places to learn from. Additionally, consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. Most frameworks have *significantly* higher quality training material.

Comment: Sir @tadman , thanks for your valuable advice. That means if I use object-oriented mysqli, there is always a lesser chance of mysql injecttion type vulnerabilities?  Also please tell me if I start using object oriented mysqli, I will not have to use parameterized query or bind_param as is done in mysqli ? Thanks in advance Sir.

Comment: The object-oriented interface means you won't accidentally confuse it with `mysql_query`, which is an unrelated and obsolete method. Parameterized queries are how you avoid SQL injection issues. It's a combination of putting `?` in your query *and* using `bind_param`. This can be tricky to get right, and the consequences of making mistakes [can be severe](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/) so always pay close attention when writing code like this and consult the manual if you're ever uncertain how to do something.

Comment: If you're not too set on `mysqli`, which is kind of a clunky and old, you may want to use PDO at an absolute minimum. Even better, consider using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) which gives you even more control. Frameworks are an improvement on this: You'll spend your time solving problems unique to your application instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks once again sir @tadman . I hope I will be able to follow your words. Currently I am using a book called Programming PHP written by Kevin Tatroe, Peter MacIntyre,Rasmus Lerdorf . Can I use it for gaining furthur knowledge?

Comment: It really depends on which edition you're using. Hopefully it's the 2013 one so you can take advantage of all the things that've happened in PHP since it was first published. That's probably a good introduction to the language itself, which is important, but knowing PHP is only part of what developing applications is about. The remainder is knowing how to organize your code, your databases, and a lot of that comes from looking at and working from good examples.

Comment: It is the 2013 edition. Thank you sir @tadman . It was really a nice experience for me while learning from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you should use the MySQL `ORDER BY` syntax.

This would be:

`SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY id ASC`

There are a lot of beginner mistakes, but since you actually are a beginner it should be okey "for the beginning" (pun intended).

Comment: Thank you sir. That fixed my code. Now I know, I am actually a beginner. :p I appreciate your quick reply sir .

Answer (score 0):

Replace your task query with the code below

```
$tasks = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tasks order by id ASC");
```

Comment: You are welcome @Sanu_012. Please make my answer as the right answer for your problem

Comment: Actually sir, the answer suggested by @Cagatay_Ulubay did my job. Thanks for providing me with the whole line but I think it the credit should go to the one who provides you the right hint at the earliest. So please bear with me this time sir.